# Seleccionar último valor de un registro en base al ID de otra tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Tengo dos tablas con los siguientes datos de ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que ocupo hacer es generar una consulta donde se muestre, agrupado por cliente, cada uno de los productos que se le han vendido y a su vez el último precio al cual se le vendió el producto, el folio de la factura que contiene el último precio y la fecha. Dando un resultado como este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando con esta consulta:

```
select distinct f.idcliente, r.idproducto, f.folio, max(f.fecha) as Fecha, r.precio from Facturas f inner join renglones r ON f.folio=r.folio group by f.idcliente,r.idproducto,f.folio,r.precio
```

Más sin embargo repite los productos por cliente y asigna su respectivo precio, más no el último.Agradezco sus sugerencias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no entendí mal, lo que buscas es algo como esto:

```
select  f.idcliente, 
        r.idproducto, 
        f.folio, 
        f.fecha, 
        r.precio 
        from Facturas f 
        inner join renglones r 
            ON f.folio=r.folio 
        inner join ( select f1.idcliente, 
                            r1.idproducto, 
                            MAX(f1.folio) as folio 
                            from Facturas f1
                            inner join renglones r1
                                ON f1.folio=r1.folio 
                            group by 
                                      f1.idcliente,
                                      r1.idproducto
                ) m
                 on m.idcliente = f.idcliente
                 and m.idproducto = r.idproducto
                 and m.folio = f.folio
```

Explicación

- En primer lugar, entiendo que para ubicar el último folio es posible usar el número del mismo mediante un `MAX(f1.folio)` en vez de la fecha, esto es un poco más sencillo.
- En la subconsulta obtenemos para cada cliente, todos los productos y el último folio de cada uno
- Teniendo esta subconsulta, lo único que resta es usarla con un `INNER JOIN` lo que en definitiva nos va a traer los últimas facturas por cada articulo que haya comprado el cliente

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Patricio Moracho. Me fue de mucha ayuda! Funciona perfectamente.